# how to reproduce this excel formula in python-pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a column representing dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd. This are sorted oldest to newest. I want to add a column next to it with the difference in time between the date at that row and the previous date.

In excel this would be something like:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you struggling with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "date" column is stored as a `datetime64` type, you can just do

```
df['difference'] = df.date.diff()
```

Check `df.dtypes` to ensure the date type is correct first.

Answer (score -1):

solved it

```
data['lowered'] = data['date'].shift(+1)

data['difference'] =  data['date'] - data['lowered']
```

Comment: That's a lot slower than calling `diff()` because you are unnecessarily creating temporary variables.